# NGINX conf file error when compiling with nginx -t

Tags: nginx

I am trying to create a mail server following [this guide](https://kirelos.com/part-3-postfixadmin-create-virtual-mailboxes-on-ubuntu-20-04-mail-server/) however when i reach the step for  `create a virtual host for PostfixAdmin` I get an error on line 15 once i run `sudo nginx -t`

`[emerg] 1209069#1209069: invalid number of arguments in "location" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/postfixadmin.conf:15`

the line on the website looks like :  `location ~ ^/(. .php)$ {`

I am unsure what it "should" look like so google searches didn't find much

Workspace:
Ubuntu 20.04
NGINX
PHP-MYSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they were trying to write was:

```
location ~ ^/(.*\.php)$ { ... }
```

but I guess their web publishing tools lost some of the characters.

However, as the capture isn't actually used within the `location` block, you can use this simplified expression instead:

```
location ~ \.php$ { ... }
```

Comment: Hello Ricahrd! Thank you! Its working now and it solved a bunch of other issues. You have my thanks again.